# Lightbox not functioning with Flexslider

Tags: javascript, flexslider

I'm using an inbuilt Wordpress lightbox known as Easy Fancybox for my gallery on the portfolio page of my website. Problem being that it doesn't work with my flexslider. I've found the cause is the jQuery library script the slider is linking to in my footer.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However without the above jQuery file, my slider doesn't work, but the lightbox does. I've tried different library's but none seem to keep both of them happy!

http://sadiemangan.co.uk/solent

Answer (score 0):

I opened console in your page and saw multiple errors and 404 one and 2 JQuery related

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at (index):486
```

this is the "on document ready" function and the error says that $ is not a function because the library is not loaded yet. typing $ in console shows that the library is loaded so it must've been loaded after document was ready

This can be solved by calling/loading the library in your page header

2nd error

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fancybox is not a function
```

this might be solved by using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $= jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

put this in header after loading your libraries

Comment: I've tried the above and it's still not working. The lightbox now functions, but the slider is not loading. :(

Comment: It seems to be kinda working now. The slider seems to now be delayed in loading time and the lightbox only works when I refresh the page for some reason. As otherwise reverts to an attachment page instead of popping up like it's meant too. Is it working your end? Why is my slider so slow now too?

Comment: Seems to keep throwing random internal server errors too.

Comment: the 2 jQuery Errors are gone from console, the slider works for me, `http://sadiemangan.co.uk/solent/wp-content/themes/thesolentelectronichome/scripts/slidepanel.js?ver=20131010` is not found (404), SyntaxHighlighter (a flexslider functions) is not defined.
I never used those two plugins before, but I'd disable one at a time and see if the SyntaxHighlighter error goes away and the light box works. some plugins might not be compatible with each others so reading FAQ or contacting support might help

Comment: I'd also check the order of js libraries loaded and make sure no function is called before defined

Comment: I may just disable the lightbox as I've changed my design so may not need it. Would you know why my slider is so slow however? I've compressed my images, is there any other way to speed the download time?